Plaid not showing previously selected accounts in update mode
I was trying to add a new account in existing account in plaid UI but when I try ,I  was not able to see the previously selected banks in the update mode UI. I was only able to select all banks from scratch. Is there a way to preselect the already checked bank accounts?
I want Plaid to show the Prechecked bank accounts

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

When launched for update mode with update.account_selection_enabled set to true, Plaid will automatically pre-select the accounts the user has already linked as long as the institution does not use its own account selection pane as part of an OAuth flow.
If the institution does use its own OAuth account selection pane, Plaid cannot pre-select the accounts the user has already linked because the pane is controlled by the financial institution and not by Plaid.
